# Error while importing lime_tabular package

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, lime

I am trying to install `lime_tabular` but this message occurs and I cannot solve it:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lime_tabular (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for lime_tabular
```

I have upgraded pip and downloaded `lime` successfully, the problem only with `lime_tabular`.

Answer (score 0):

[`lime_tabular`](https://lime-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lime.html#module-lime.lime_tabular) is a module in the `lime` package. After running `pip install lime`, import with:

```py
from lime import lime_tabular
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a requirements.txt file in your project directory, check the version written there. Maybe the version mentioned there is not correct. Remove the version number from there. Try to install again using

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

**OR**
If this package is installing a dependency of another package installation. Try to Upgrade the versions as well.

**OR** 
If any of the two solution doesn't fix your solution. What u can do is to check the current version of this package and install it directly in your virtual environment or your current environment. Using

```
pip install <package-name>
```

After manually installing all the dependency packages then install your desired package. \

After installing try to import using the correct syntax

```
from lime import lime_tabular
or
import lime.lime_tabular
or
self.explainer =  lime.lime_tabular.LimeTabularExplainer() // like this
```

I hope you find it useful.